# how to transfer database from gce instance to openshift gear

Tags: mongodb, openshift, google-compute-engine

I have an application running on the google compute engine. It's a nodejs application connected to a mongodb instance. This instance has documents, the accounts of people registered on my website. I want to transfer this data to my openshift gear. It's the same application, I just want to migrate the data to mongodb on openshift.

Comment: If you would like to transfer your website to OpenShift from GCE, you will need to export the mongodb database out of gce, and then import it into a mongodb database running on OpenShift.  What have you tried so far? What errors did you get?

Comment: How do I export the mongodb database out of gce?

Comment: You should try asking in the gce forums about that.